# Laravel | Chamar variavel na view

Tags: laravel, id, chat

Preciso de uma ajuda para perceber o que estou a fazer de errado.
Estou a construir um chat onde do lado direito tenho os utilizadores e que ao clicar no utilizador abra o chat respetivo.

Nos utilizadores do lado direito coloquei o seguinte HREF:

```
 <a href="{{route('chat.index', ['id'=>$item->id])}}">
```

Que depois coloca o seguinte link na página :

```
 /Chat?id=10
```

e coloquei na view se existe id mostra o chat.

```
@if($id)
```

Mas não vem até aqui. Não consigo fazer com que o IF seja verdadeiro.

No controller tenho o seguinte código, mas acho que não está errado.

```
        $outroUser = null;
    if($id){
        $outroUser = utilizador::findorfail($id);
      
    }


    $tabela = utilizador::orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
    return view('painel-admin.chat.index', ['itens' => $tabela, $outroUser]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Você não está passando o valor como `$id` do controller para a view, e sim o valor de `$outroUser` que vira uma chave numérica no array.

Altere ao chamar a view:

```php
    return view('painel-admin.chat.index', ['itens' => $tabela, 'id' => $outroUser]);
```